# JAXB marshalling exception - as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, jaxb

I am trying to consume a SOAP api and using JAXB plugin to generate Java classes from the WSDL.
But I am getting following exception:

> org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]

I added following piece of code:

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SendSms.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        JAXBElement<SendSms> root = new ObjectFactory().createSendSms(sendSms1);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
```

But still getting this exception on the following line:

```
            JAXBElement<SendSmsResponse> response = (JAXBElement<SendSmsResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("MyUrl", sendSms);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen same error.

Comment: Create JAXBElement like this maybe: `new JAXBElement<SendSms>(new QName("uri","local"), SendSms.class, sendSms1);` ?

Comment: ObjectFactory does the same what's the difference?